# How can i detect if a value is in my list of this type in python?

Tags: python

i have this tilemap list, that is used to draw the tilemap:

```
tilemap =  [['W','W','W','W','W','W','W','W','W'],
            ['W',0,0,0,0,0,0,'E','W'],
            ['W',0,r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),0,'W'],
            ['W',0,r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),0,'W'],
            ['W',0,r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),0,'W'],
            ['W',0,r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),0,'W'],
            ['W',0,r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),0,'W'],
            ['W',0,r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),r.randint(0,20),0,'W'],
            ['W','P',0,0,0,0,0,0,'W'],
            ['W','W','W','W','W','W','W','W','W']]
```

And i want to check if it contains the value 9 or 20, but if i do for example `if 0 in tilemap` i get False, although i do have 0, i can tell it is because it only detects the first column, or row, i dont really know, but how can i detect if a specific value is this type of list?

Answer (score 0):

you can either flatten the list and check for 0 or check each sub-list individually

```
tilemap = [[1], [1,2,3], [0]]

truth = [0 in x for x in tilemap]
print(True in truth)
#True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r = [True if 0 in i else False for i in tilemap]
ans = [True if True in r else False][0]
print(ans)
```

it will check only one occurrence of desired value in tilemap